# Crystal Reports 2008 unable to link parameters to subreport

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

In Crystal Reports 2008 I have a main report with arg_beg_date and arg_end_date parameters. I want to pass these to a subreport, but have not been able to. The subreport has a Command with a SQL query in it - SELECT * FROM TXFR to keep it simple. I created two parameters in the subreport named beg_date and end_date, then adding WHERE TXFR_DATE BETWEEN {?BEG_DATE} AND {?END_DATE} to the query. I tried to Change Subreport Links, find arg_beg_date in the Available Fields, and clicked ">" to move it to the Field(s) to link to box.

At that point I only see ?Pm-?arg_beg_date and "Parameter Fields" as choices in the "Subreport parameter field to use" box. I cannot link arg_beg_date from the main report to the beg_date parameter I created in the subreport.

I saw in another question where someone suggested checking the box for "Select date for subreport based on field" and selecting "report fields", but I am unable to do that. It just highlights and selects a field below that in the box.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I've recently built the same report where the Subreport is a command line.  I haven't written up a procedure yet but this is how the parameter should look like if you are passing a parameter from the main report to the sub report.

In your subreport SQL, the parameter must be this

**WHERE TXFR_DATE BETWEEN {?Pm-?arg_beg_date} AND {?Pm-?arg_end_date}**

Then in your parameter list, create

- **Pm-?arg_beg_date**
- **Pm-?arg_end_date**

In your main report, Change Subreport links...

1. Add the ?arg_beg_date parameter
2. Make sure the "Select data in subreport based on field" is unchecked
3. Do the same for ?arg_end_date parameter

In case you want to pass a field instead of a parameter and you are using a command in your main report, same steps as above but looks like this.

Subreport SQL

{?Pm-Command.FieldName}

Parameter List

Pm-Command.FieldName

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. The parameters were not showing up in the list to be linked to, because the types did not match. The parameter type in my main report is DateTime, and the type in my subreport was Date. They have to match exactly.

Thanks for your help.